# Using redux state in local state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying figure out why I can't define my redux state into my local state. Basically I'm try to give `displayed` the value of `this.props.tournaments` so I can manipulate the state. But every time I define it and `console.log(this.state.displayed)` as shown in the `renderList` function, it spits out an empty array however if I `console.log(this.props.tournaments)` I get the data I need from my api, any ideas?

Here is what I'm working with:

**the main component**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

import { fetchTournaments } from '../actions/tournaments';
import Item from './Item';
import EditTournament from './EditTournament';

import '../styles/Item.css';

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchTerm: '',
      displayed: this.props.tournaments
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.displayed, 'here');
    this.props.fetchTournaments();
  }

  async handleDelete(id) {
    const url = `http://localhost:4000/tournaments/`;

    await axios
      .delete(url + id)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  renderList() {
    let array = this.props.tournaments;

     console.log(this.state.displayed);
     console.log(this.props.tournament);

    return array.map(tournament => {
      return tournament.map(item => {
        if (!this.props.tournaments) {
          return <div className="button">Loading....</div>;
        } else {
          return (
            <Item
              key={item.id}
              name={item.name}
              organizer={item.organizer}
              participants={Object.values(item.participants)}
              game={item.game}
              start={item.startDate}
            >
              <div className="buttonBar">
                <EditTournament id={item.id} name={item.name} />
                <button
                  className="button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    if (
                      window.confirm(
                        'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'
                      )
                    ) {
                      this.handleDelete(item.id);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </Item>
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="row">{this.renderList()}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ tournaments }) {
  return {
    tournaments: Object.keys(tournaments).map(key => tournaments[key])
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchTournaments
})(List);
```

**what it looks like after I console.log(this.props.tournaments):**

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c06ae.png)

**what it looks like after I console.log(this.state.displayed)**

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEw5y.png)

**Data from API:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "9c430783-dc3a-4114-954a-c041e9350c81",
    "name": "Fuga Repellendus Quibusdam Neque",
    "organizer": "Perferendis Omnis",
    "game": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
    "participants": {
      "current": 190,
      "max": 256
    },
    "startDate": "2020-06-12T18:58:14.837Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "1919af3f-cde0-4ca4-83fa-e0ae1cfa9a9c",
    "name": "Qui Voluptatem Impedit",
    "organizer": "Dolore Quae",
    "game": "League of Legends",
    "participants": {
      "current": 182,
      "max": 256
    },
    "startDate": "2020-06-12T18:58:14.837Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "4b806324-bc63-4fb0-a30e-c3a42099c510",
    "name": "Earum Ut Omnis",
    "organizer": "Officia Cupiditate",
    "game": "Rocket League",
    "participants": {
      "current": 56,
      "max": 256
    },
    "startDate": "2020-06-12T18:58:14.837Z"
  },
]
```

my redux actions

```
import {
  FETCH_TOURNAMENTS,

} from './types';

import { API_TOURNAMENTS_URL } from '../constants/api';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchTournaments = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(API_TOURNAMENTS_URL);

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOURNAMENTS, payload: response.data });
};
```

**my reducers**

```
import {
  FETCH_TOURNAMENTS,
} from '../actions/types';

export default (state = {}, action, value: '') => {
  switch (action.type) {
 
    case FETCH_TOURNAMENTS:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
 
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why did you want to copy state data that is already available through redux state to your local state?

Answer (score 1):

First, **data won't be available when your constructor gets called**,

And you are initializing the state inside the state, so if you want to update state also whenever there is a change in props, You can use :

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
  // set your state here
}
```

**But, I don't suggest this**

As you are already mapping stateToProps, that will cause the re-render as there are any changes in your `tournaments`, so you can use that props only for displaying purpose and **if you want to make any change you should `dispatch` event**, this is how you should do in `react-redux` architecture.

And your `console.log` showing the correct result, this is how it works

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this:

```
this.state = {
  searchTerm: '',
  displayed: this.props.tournaments
};
```

instead use `getDerivedStateFromProps` function or `setState` inside `componentDidMount`

the reason it isn't showing is because `setState` is async

`setState` takes a second argument of a callback that you could use to be sure that state has been set and then call a function in the callback

Answer (score 0):

It is about [life cycle](https://i0.wp.com/programmingwithmosh.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-31-at-1.44.28-PM.png?ssl=1) of the React component. Your constructor method called just once when the component was created and won't update after updating your props.

`componenedDidMount` method updates your redux store but doesn't touch your local state. You can sync your redux state and local state in `componentDidUpdate` method of your component. Don't use `componentWillReceiveProps` It's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This is because of two reasons :

1. Since value of `tournaments` is set asynchronously in redux upon calling the function `fetchTournaments`, the initial value of `displayed` in local state will be the initial value of `tournaments` in redux i.e. empty array.
2. Constructor is run only once, so even after data is fetched and in redux you have new value for `tournaments`. Your state value remains unaffected. Hence the `undefined` in `console.log`

In order to remedy this,

1. You should set the state of `displayed` only when there is a change in the value of `tournaments` prop. Like so -

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 // compare this.props and nextProps and set state here
}
```

Additionally, as a general practise, I would recommend not setting the value of state to a prop in constructor, instead use initial state.
i.e.

```
this.state = {
  searchTerm: '',
  displayed: []
}
```